# Infinitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\mu(n) + \mu(n+1) = 0 $.

Tags: number-theory

I try to show that there are infinitely many numbers $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\mu(n) + \mu(n+1) = 0 $.

---

*What I did*

We write $\mathcal{P}$ for the set of prime numbers. 
We need to show that one of the following sets is infinite:
$$
A \quad = \quad 
\{ n \ : \ \exists p,q \in \mathcal{P}, \ p^2|n \ \text{ and }  \ q^2 | (n+1) \   \}
$$
$$
B \quad = \quad
\{ n \ : \ \omega(p)=-\omega(q) \text{ and $p,q$ are square free} \}
$$

There are no upper bounds for the sets 
$\mu^{-1}(\{ -1\}), \ \mu^{-1}(\{ 0\}), \ \mu^{-1}(\{ 1\})$.

I find it very hard to say something about $n+1$, given that we have the factorisation of $n$. All I know is that $p | n  \ \Rightarrow \ p \nmid n+1$.

---

Could you give me **a hint** to show that either $A$ or $B$ is infinite? Please don't give a full answer.

---

**Attempt to use the hint I got**

I understand that we can choose $x$ as big as we need. Obviously, $x^p$ as divided be some square prime. Here I try to show that $x^p +1 $ is not squarefree.  We know that $x+1 \ | \ x^p+1$, and
$p \ | \ x+1$ so $p \ | \  x^p+1$. Now we need to show that

$$
p  \ | \  \frac{x^p+1}{x+1}
$$
We have in $\mathbb{F}_p$ that
$$
\frac{x^p+1}{x+1} \ = \ \frac{(x+1-1)^p+1}{x+1} 
\ = \ \frac{(x+1)^p + (-1)^p + 1}{x+1} = (x+1)^{p-1} \ = \ 0
$$
as required.

Comment: You have to show that $p\mid (x^p+1)/(x+1)$ using the fact that $x\equiv -1 \pmod p$. This is a particular case of the lifting the exponent lemma that I linked you below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ be any integer such that there exists an odd prime $p$ such that $p\mid x+1$. Then $x^p+1$ is non square-free by [lifting the exponent](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Resources/Papers/LTE.pdf) and $\mu(x^p)+\mu(x^p+1)=0$.

Comment: could you say one more thing about the fact that $x^p + 1$ is not squarefree? It is the only thing that I don't get.

Comment: @KoenraadvanDuin If $x\equiv -1 \pmod{p}$, then $\frac{x^p+1}{x+1} = x^{p-1} - x^{p-2} + \cdots \pm 1$ is easily seen to be divisible by $p$, so $x^p+1$ is divisible by $p^2$.  Lifting the exponent is not necessary here (the hard part of that theorem is that this quantity is _not_ divisible by $p^2$, which we don't need here).

Answer (score 3):

For every integer of the form $n=36k+8$,
$$
\mu(n)+\mu(n+1)=0+0=0.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Consider the two neighbours of an odd prime. One is even, and the other is more even.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n+1$ be the square of an odd number. Then, we know that $n$ is divisible by $4$, so both $n$ and $n+1$ are killed by $\mu$.